# How to make css class to work only inside of one component?

Tags: html, css

```css
.vh {position: absolute !important; 
clip:rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
padding: 0 !important; 
border: 0 !important;
height: 1px !important;
width: 1px !important; 
overflow: hidden;
}


label:before {content: ''; width: 16px;
height: 16px; 
background: #fff; 
border: 1px solid rgba(75, 101, 132, 0.3); 
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 16px;
}



input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label:before {background: #3b17bb no-repeat center; 
background-size: 12px 12px; 
background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;utf8;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iaXNvLTg4NTktMSI/Pgo8IS0tIEdlbmVyYXRvcjogQWRvYmUgSWxsdXN0cmF0b3IgMTYuMC4wLCBTVkcgRXhwb3J0IFBsdWctSW4gLiBTVkcgVmVyc2lvbjogNi4wMCBCdWlsZCAwKSAgLS0+CjwhRE9DVFlQRSBzdmcgUFVCTElDICItLy9XM0MvL0RURCBTVkcgMS4xLy9FTiIgImh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnL0dyYXBoaWNzL1NWRy8xLjEvRFREL3N2ZzExLmR0ZCI+CjxzdmcgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB4bWxuczp4bGluaz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMTk5OS94bGluayIgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4xIiBpZD0iQ2FwYV8xIiB4PSIwcHgiIHk9IjBweCIgd2lkdGg9IjE2cHgiIGhlaWdodD0iMTZweCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDQ1LjcwMSA0NS43IiBzdHlsZT0iZW5hYmxlLWJhY2tncm91bmQ6bmV3IDAgMCA0NS43MDEgNDUuNzsiIHhtbDpzcGFjZT0icHJlc2VydmUiPgo8Zz4KCTxnPgoJCTxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0yMC42ODcsMzguMzMyYy0yLjA3MiwyLjA3Mi01LjQzNCwyLjA3Mi03LjUwNSwwTDEuNTU0LDI2LjcwNGMtMi4wNzItMi4wNzEtMi4wNzItNS40MzMsMC03LjUwNCAgICBjMi4wNzEtMi4wNzIsNS40MzMtMi4wNzIsNy41MDUsMGw2LjkyOCw2LjkyN2MwLjUyMywwLjUyMiwxLjM3MiwwLjUyMiwxLjg5NiwwTDM2LjY0Miw3LjM2OGMyLjA3MS0yLjA3Miw1LjQzMy0yLjA3Miw3LjUwNSwwICAgIGMwLjk5NSwwLjk5NSwxLjU1NCwyLjM0NSwxLjU1NCwzLjc1MmMwLDEuNDA3LTAuNTU5LDIuNzU3LTEuNTU0LDMuNzUyTDIwLjY4NywzOC4zMzJ6IiBmaWxsPSIjRkZGRkZGIi8+Cgk8L2c+CjwvZz4KPGc+CjwvZz4KPGc+CjwvZz4KPGc+CjwvZz4KPGc+CjwvZz4KPGc+CjwvZz4KPGc+CjwvZz4KPGc+CjwvZz4KPGc+CjwvZz4KPGc+CjwvZz4KPGc+CjwvZz4KPGc+CjwvZz4KPGc+CjwvZz4KPGc+CjwvZz4KPGc+CjwvZz4KPGc+CjwvZz4KPC9zdmc+Cg==);}



input[type="checkbox"]:focus ~ label {color: #3b17bb;}
```

```html
 <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        id="1" class="vh"
                        checked="checked" 
                        name="sameadr"
                      />
                      <label for="1"></label>
```

How to make css code, To work only inside of one component, Because i am inside of x component and in y component i have some checkbox, So there also same css class is reflecting.

But i need to make it work inisde of x component only.

Comment: Give the css component a class programmatically.

Comment: @Laif  Sorry changed it now

Comment: I wasn't telling you to change your question, I was saying that was the solution.

Comment: No i haven't changed my code, I have aligned the css code. 

 in my case i have vh class. I am doing the custom checkbox. But issue is it is reflecting in other components also. So i want to make the css class to work inside of one component only

Comment: Please read the comment I added on my answer

Answer (score 0):

Give the element another classname, that has the CSS you want on it, for instance:

```html
<input class="vh" />
<input class="vh" />
<input class="vh red-border" />
```

```css
.vh{
    color: green;
}

.red-border{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```